# Change table column order based on option select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, html-table

So, i have table like this:

```
<table class="ui-responsive ui-shadow gk-decorate table-stripe" is="jqm-table" data-role="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>E</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the user can show certain columns based on a filter in a select option. 
Which works fine so far using the nth-child selector: `$('td:nth-child(x),th:nth-child(x)').hide();`
The filter looks something like that: `"A,B,C,F"`
 e.g.: instead the original table he gets the right table:

**Original Table**    **Filterd Table**

> A B C D E F     --> A B C F
>   A B C D E F     --> A B C F
>   A B C D E F     --> A B C F
>   A B C D E F     --> A B C F
>   A B C D E F     --> A B C F

Now comes my question how can i also change the order of the Columns? when i have filter like so: `"A, C, B, D"`
**Original Table**    **Filterd Table**

> A B C D E F     --> A C B D
>   A B C D E F     --> A C B D
>   A B C D E F     --> A C B D
>   A B C D E F     --> A C B D
>   A B C D E F     --> A C B D

**UPDATE:**
 what i tried so far is using the detach function to switch the columns. Something like that:
  `var cols = $("#tableId").children(td, th);`
`cols.eq(0).detach().insertBefore(cols.eq(1));`
But no sucess what so ever. Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0nz3qu0/1/)

Comment: well what have you tried?

Comment: Where is your select options tag? Show us your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes buddy, Especially for people like you `CSS3 Flexbox` was introduced as a boon to solve these kinda issues!

> **FYI: I have done the changes only for "AED" option for you.**

You can easily solve this by using **Flexbox**, [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x0nz3qu0/2/) is updated & I have also improved the way in which you can achieve the goal(minimal javascript used), much cleaner.

**What have i done?**

1. When selecting an option I used JS to just add a class to all the `tr` & in CSS I made the styles available for that class. Elegant & clean!
2. Now to change the order, use flexbox. Add `display: flex;` to the parent container of the elements you want to move, in your case all the `tr` are the parent containers since you want to move the `th` & `td`.
3. Now whenever you want, change the property called `order`(by default its 0) to any of the element you want to move. Simple

**Note ::** - The element with a higher value of `order` property will be shown later. So basically the elements are shown according to the **increasing** value of the `order` property. [how order works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order).

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer your example is really nice and works well, but unfortunately i cannot use the "display: flex" option because it destroys my whole table :(

Comment: I see, that part is easy to fix don't worry. It should be much easier to use flex & correct the table than using hacks & complicating the structure. Tell me how using flex is destroying your table(using a fiddle or so), I will be able to fix it. It probably requires 1 or so property added. I am guessing your table contents are going horizontal rather than vertical ?

Comment: Good day Sir, here is a new fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/2q5a5zfv/1/. If you uncomment the {display: flex} the width of the table is changing to a minimum i tried forcing the width to 100% but it didnt work :(.

Comment: Hey buddy fixed your problem :-). All you needed was the width of all `<td>`s & `<th>`s to be made 100%, the "flex" way .. Add this line `table tr td, table tr th {flex-basis: 100%;}` [Fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/2q5a5zfv/2/)

Comment: Hey, yep that does the trick thanks alot i will mark this as the correct answer. Unfortunately this doenst work in IE11 or Edge any Idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, IE is weird(as usual) - It supports flexbox but not the "flex-basis" property. You could instead use `table tr td, table tr th {flex: 1 1 auto;}`. This works across all browsers including IE11. `flex` is a shorthand combination property of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` & `flex-basis` in that order. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2q5a5zfv/4/) here. Hope this helped

Comment: Still only working in Firefox RIP. But thank you for your time +1;

Comment: Yeah thats an IE bug noted [here](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#7-flex-basis-doesnt-account-for-box-sizingborder-box). You can add `width: 25%;`, like so `table tr td, table tr th {flex: 0 1 100%; width: 25%;}` to fix it on IE - tested